# Avoid ../../../ require in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating an express 4 project and many of my files are nested within folders. Unfortunately I using a lot of :

```
var x = require('../../../../file');
```

I'm thinking I can avoid this if I have access to the base url of the project, but I'm seeing that using a global variable isn't a good idea. What's the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want directory of the root script from which the node process started, you can get it like this:

```
var root = require.main.filename.slice(0,require.main.filename.lastIndexOf('/'))
```

or, as @ChiChou suggested:

```
var root = require('path').dirname(require.main.filename)
```

This assumes that the main script (or any other script that requires your code) is run from the root directory.

You can use this `root` as your "base url".

Comment: `var root = require('path').dirname(require.main.filename)` may be better.

Comment: good suggestion ill add it to the answer